# QNetworkAccessManager - set active/passive ftp modes

Tags: qt, qt4

I would like to be able to set the FTP mode (active or passive) when I use QNetworkAccessManager.

QFtp has setTransferMode(), is there a way to do this with QNetworkAccessManager?

Comment: Keeping requests/replies properly paired is tedious.  Also, cancel() does not work well when you have commands queued since it leaves you  in a unknown (as or compile time) state (did it cancel a close() or not?).  

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qftp.html#details "However, for new applications, it is recommended to use QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply, as those classes possess a simpler, yet more powerful API."

Comment: Hmm... I was not aware of the limitations of the QFtp API. I imagine that under the hood of QFtp, there's some sort of QNetworkAccessManager but I don't know too much about the QFtp architecture.